# Can i login into specific account on google drive api?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have an Android app, and I would like to make something like a wall that everyone can post on. This should not be something very stressful, so I wanted a free option to make it 24/7 and gDocs came up in my mind. But I would need use it "undercovered" so people can't mess it up. So, I think I have to login with the admin account and manipulate all the creation and update without the user intervention, just display the fields I need. So, can I login to a specific gDocs account by code, or I always have to use the user account?

I know it's not the best option, but it's an free app, and I don't wanna have any cost with this. Also, I didn't start the development yet, just want to know if it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log into gDocs with any account you have user and password to.
remember that you have to store the password of that account inside the app (**unsafe**)

I would recommend you a free webhost with mysql and query a html-request to a php-document for posting on your wall. There you can controll every post with php. reading posts goes over another php-document. Since you define the format, you can have a website showing your wall and android gets a csv containing only data.

Comment: Thanks Kostronor. I thought about using a free webhost, but they usually are free until a limit of traffic, I don't know how much traffic it'll get, so I want something unlimited. But thanks for your concern!